# Sybase system procedure - how to get result?

Tags: database, t-sql, stored-procedures, sybase, sap-ase

Is there any way of saving the result set of a **SYSTEM** procedure in **Sybase ASE 15**?

For example, if i want to get details about all the columns of a table, i would use the following code:
 `sp_columns 'TABLE_NAME'`.

I want to save the result into a temporary table or get it by using a cursor to use it for other queries. Is there any way of doing it?

Note: I am aware i could write my query by using the system tables and get the same result, but if this is possible, i would prefer this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system stored procedures are not intended to be used for inputs into other tables/procedures. 
If you don't want to write your own queries, you can look at the code behind the stored procedure by using `sp_helptext`.  For system stored procedures you need to be in the `sybsystemprocs` db.

```
use sybsystemprocs
go    
sp_helptext sp_columns
go
```

From there you can take a look at what is being queried and just grab what you need.

It's also helpful to take a look at the Sybase [ASE System Tables Diagram](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc70204.1550/pdf/a155pst.pdf?noframes=true):  This shows all the system tables, and all the relationships between tables.

Comment: thanks, Michael... honestly, i was waiting towards your answer. Looks like i will write my own queries, the system procedures contain much more information than i actually need. By the way, thanks for the diagram link. i will treasure it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use proxy tables to store the output of the SP in table.

[This example](http://www.sypron.nl/proctab.html) is very helpful